# Out-file issues

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I have this script

```
ForEach ($u in $usersFromFile)
{
try{
    $nomailbox = if (-not (get-mailbox $u.alias)){   
    $notfound = $notfound + $nomailbox
        Write-host "No mailbox for "$u.alias -F blue|out-file "d:\scripts\nomailbox.txt"}
    }   

Catch{}
```

Nothing is written to the outfile

What am I missing?

TIA

Andy

Comment: `Write-Host` writes to **host** (or to information stream) not to output.

Comment: [`Write-Host` Considered Harmful](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PowerShell version lower than 5, Out-Host writes to host, just like PetSerAl said, you should use Write-Output, instead. With PS 5 you can use Out-Host to achieve what previously couldn't be achieved with Out-Host.

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
ForEach ($u in $usersFromFile) { try{
    $nomailbox = if (-not (get-mailbox $u.alias)){   
    $notfound = $notfound + $nomailbox
        Write-Output "No mailbox for "$u.alias -F blue|out-file "d:\scripts\nomailbox.txt"}
    }   

Catch{}
```

This should work. But i think, youre not gonna color this line without a reason.. You can use this with a function too:

```
function writehosttofile {
Param(
 [switch]$para
)
Write-Host "No mailbox for "$u.alias -F blue

if($para){
"No mailbox for " + $u.alias
}

}

writehosttofile -para | out-file "d:\scripts\nomailbox.txt"
```

> ## Write-Host
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> Write-Host sends the objects to the host. It does not return any objects.

You can also browse to your script and redirect **all** output in a file:

```
PS C:\temp> cd c:\bin
PS C:\bin> .\script.ps1 > C:\bin\script_output.txt
```

have a nice day.